# How to have a Column of 2 text widgets to be either side of a central x axis in a row

Tags: dart, flutter

The image contains a column of two text widgets which is centered aligned with the icon. But I I'd like the column of text BOTH lines to.... to have one line of text above the centre x axis(of the icon) and one line below.

[image]

Here is my code..

```
               Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SvgPicture.asset('assets/icon/but_headphones_${widget.pillarColorNames[program.pillar-1]}.svg',height: 60,),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(session.name.toUpperCase(), style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline.merge(TextStyle(color: widget.pillarCollors[program.pillar-1])),),
                                Text(session.description, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Text(duration, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Color.fromRGBO(170, 170, 170, 1)),),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

EDIT: update code to reflect image

Comment: Do you want a line above and below of the Row?

Comment: I want the the smaller text and larger text grouped together and then centred as one ...if that makes any sense. At thew moment the smaller text looks odd

Comment: did you try to use 'Center' to contain the column that contains the texts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the text column mainAxisAlignment to spaceBetween?

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
```

So your code would be like this:

```
Expanded(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(session.name.toUpperCase(), style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline.merge(TextStyle(color: widget.pillarCollors[program.pillar-1])),),
            Text(session.description, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,),
          ],
        ),
      )
),
```

Another solution would be placing each text widget inside a separate Row and then put a SizedBox between the rows. This way you could manually set the height of the SizedBox to match the space you want between the lines.